# In Python how do you convert strings in a list of list to other types, such as ints, floats, booleans, etc?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When given a list of data, I'm being asked to convert strings within the list to a corresponding type, such as int if the string contains a whole number, or a float if it doesn't contain a whole number. But I'm running into this problem where it will convert the value but it doesn't change the original value in the list.

For example, if given:

```
d = [['abc', '123', '45.6', 'True', 'False']]
```

It's supposed to look like this after the conversion:

```
[['abc', 123, 45.6, True, False]]
```

So far I've tried to write a for loop and convert the values that way but as I mentioned it doesn't change the original list:

```
for lst in data:
    for index in lst:
        if index.isdigit():
            index = int(index)
        elif not index.isdigit():
            index = float(index)
```

I'm not really sure how to fix the problem or if it's there's another way to go about it. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the items at the initial indices using list subscription i.e. assigning to each index after *casting* the item. You can do this using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) which supplies each item in the list with a corresponding index:

```
import ast

d = [['abc', '123', '45.6', 'True', 'False']]

for lst in d:
  for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    try:
        lst[i] = ast.literal_eval(x)
    except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
        lst[i] = x
print(d)
# [['abc', 123, 45.6, True, False]]
```

[`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) tries to parse each string item as a Python literal, if that fails (with error), revert to the original item (see [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp)).

If you have a large number of these strings, it would be faster (although with less cleaner code and maybe prone to errors) to write your own parser, however, it's probably better to let `ast.literal_eval` do all the *dirty* work.

Comment: Good idea. It seems to be not documented, but `literal_eval` may raise also a `SyntaxError` (try e.g."123A"). Maybe other errors too, I don't know exactly. BTW, a simple `pass` would do in the `except` clause.

Comment: @VPfB Thanks for noting. I'll just add that to the exceptions to watch for.

Answer (score 1):

Here without any libraries. Just slice the things and some try-except tricks. `isdigit()` checks if the `string` is `digit`, if it's not, then that means it is `float`. For `True` and `False`, just checking if they are in the list.

This can be done shorter, I just made it this way so you can see how it works.

```
all = [['abc', '123', '45.6', 'True', 'False']]

for d in all:
    for x,y in enumerate(d):
        if y == "True":
            d[x] = True
        if y == "False":
            d[x] = False

for d in all:
    for x,y in enumerate(d):
        try:
            if y.isdigit() == True:
                d[x] = int(y)
            else:
                d[x] = float(y)
        except:
            pass
```

Output;

```
['abc', 123, 45.6, True, False]

abc
<class 'str'>
123
<class 'int'>
45.6
<class 'float'>
True
<class 'bool'>
False
<class 'bool'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This ( No Library Needed ):

```
data = [['abc', '123', '45.6', 'True', 'False']]


def isfloat(x):
    try:
        a = float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def isint(x):
    try:
        a = float(x)
        b = int(a)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return a == b


for counter1, box in enumerate(data):

    for counter2, items in enumerate(box):

        if isfloat(items) is True:
            data[counter1][counter2] = float(items)

        elif isint(items) is True:
            data[counter1][counter2] = float(items)

        elif items == "True":
            data[counter1][counter2] = True

        elif items == "False":
            data[counter1][counter2] = False

        else:
            pass

print(data)
```